# App continues to use default icon despite all icons being set in Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The app is being tested on a physical iOS device - an iPad with iOS 12.4 installed. This is on Windows 10 with Hot Restart. I have not tried on a simulator or without hot restart as I do not have a Mac at hand.

I have set all images in the AppIcons from the Asset Catalog (called 'Media'). AppIcons has been set to in Visual Assets under Info.plist. However, all icons used in the application still use the default Xamarin logo.

I noticed that the default logos were hidden from the Solution Explorer, but are under Resources in the file explorer. I removed them to see whether the icon would display the empty wireframe logo, however, the default logo is still displayed.

One solution said that this is due to caching, therefore the test device should have the app removed and should be restarted. This did not do anything.

The asset catalog has been deleted and recreated a couple times in an attempt to fix this issue. Nothing.

The path in Info.plist is correct, not directing to another folder.

[image: Screenshot proving AppIcons has been set]

[image: Screenshot of Info.plist for the icon set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Supposedly](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1010619/using-xamarin-hot-restart-to-debug-on-ios-phone-do.html), Hot Restart for iOS does not support custom icons, and will always use the default icons no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `Assets file path` doesn't match the vaule in `info.plist`.

Try to change

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Media.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
```

to

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, my Catalog is called Media and not Assets. Even when it was called Assets, this issue existed.

Comment: @DaddyProphet Did you try to put the icon into the default Assets,don't create a new  Asset Catalog,and see if it work.

Comment: Yes, I had originally used the default catalog, but that didn't work at all, so I attempted to recreate a catalog, deleting the default and making a new one.

Comment: @DaddyProphet It's weird.I could not reproduce your issue,both the original and recreated catalog work.Maybe you could try to create a new project.

Comment: I created a new project and installed app on the same iPad Air running iOS 12. Set the iPad specific icons for the home screen, still using default icons. Could it have anything to do with installing the debug version or Hot Restart?

Comment: @DaddyProphet Maybe you could look at [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/126052/workaround-for-the-ios-app-icon-not-appearing-bug).Hope it will be helpful to you.